Setting image with proper margins due to header using python-docx
My task is to automate the formatting of a document according to the user's input. I had to add cover and back page images with smaller margins than the rest of the document. I figured out how to add the cover page image with some help from ChatGPT, but I am unable to figure out how to properly add a back page image. The problem I'm facing is when adding a new section(since I need different margins), it inherits the header and footer property from the previous section. To prevent this I used is_linked_to_previous = False for both header and footer. But it didn't quite work. On examining the XML of the docx produced, I found that the new section still had references for header and footer and even the page margin had tags for header and footer which I guess are taking the extra space.
Following is the XML:
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="00C84B07" w:rsidRPr="00813D6B">
    <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId13" />
    <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId14" />
    <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
    <w:pgMar w:top="288" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="288" w:header="708"
        w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
    <w:cols w:space="708" />
    <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
</w:sectPr>

Shouldn't the headerReference and footerReference not be present since I have mentioned not the link to previous. Same goes for the w:header and w:footer tags in <w:pgMar>.
I have used the following code to add a back page image:
def add_back_page_image(doc, image, margin_size=Inches(0.2)):
    """Adding a back page image."""

    back_section = doc.add_section()
    back_section.header.is_linked_to_previous = False
    back_section.footer.is_linked_to_previous = False
    back_section.top_margin = margin_size
    back_section.left_margin = margin_size

    image_width = back_section.page_width - margin_size * 2
    image_height = back_section.page_height - margin_size * 2

    back_paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
    back_paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER    

    back_paragraph.add_run().add_picture(image, width=image_width, height=image_height)

This is the result obtained: The gap between top of the image and top of the page is larger than the top margin I have defined.
This is what I was expecting. This is the cover page image. The gap between image and top of the page is the margin I have defined.

The gap between top of the image and top of the page is back_section.top_margin plus back_section.header_distance. Try setting back_section.header_distance = 0. Is this then what you want?  But the is_linked_to_previous = False works for me. The new section needs references for header and footer precisely because is not is linked to the previous. But this are different references than for the previous section. Same for page settings.

Hey Alex thanks for your comment. I tired back_section.header_distance = 0 but there is still a small gap between the top of the image and the page, which is more than the margin I have set.

Since it is an inline picture:     back_paragraph.paragraph_format.line_spacing_rule = WD_LINE_SPACING.SINGLE and back_paragraph.paragraph_format.space_before = 0 and back_paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = 0
